# Center ngx-pagination

Tags: css, angular, center, ngx-pagination

I have an ngx-pagination :

```
<pagination-controls
                  id="pagination"
                  (pageChange)="page = $event"
                  (pageBoundsCorrection)="page = $event"
                  [maxSize]="9"
                  [directionLinks]="true"
                  [autoHide]="true"
                  [responsive]="true"
                  previousLabel="Previous"
                  nextLabel="Next"
                  screenReaderPaginationLabel="Pagination"
                  screenReaderPageLabel="page"
                  screenReaderCurrentLabel="You're on page">
</pagination-controls>
```

Things with center like :

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <my-pagination></my-pagination>
</div>
```

are not working, cause the **width** of the pagination is alwayws 100% **width** of the page.

How can i make **width** of the pagination as small as possible and keep it responsible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
.mat-paginator-container {
  width: fit-content !important;
}
```

And if you want to center it everywhere add this too:

```
.mat-paginator-outer-container {
  justify-content: center !important;
}
```